# Building Crypto++ for Android and Using DefaultEncryptorWithMAC?

Tags: android, android-ndk, crypto++

I need to use the Crytopp ([link](https://github.com/cawka/cryptopp-1/tree/android)) library. I don't need much I just need to encrypt and decrypt some files using DefaultEncryptorWithMAC and DefaultDecryptorWithMAC.

I'm pretty new in android native development and more noob in cryptography. Can anyone walk me through the process of installing, building calling these function from local module...?? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Crypto++ has an Android tutorial at [Android (Command Line)](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Android_%28Command_Line%29). There are also discussion on occasion at the [User Group](http://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/cryptopp-users).

Comment: yeah I saw that... and as I told you... I don't have any prior experience of working with android NDK... it couldn't make much sense of it.. :/

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what Stack Overflow can do for you. The site wants closed-ended questions; and questions like tutorial walk-throughs are off-topic. We provided you with a link to the process, but you rejected it due to lack of experience. It sounds like you need to start building your body of knowledge in this area. Perhaps you should start with the [Android Hello JNI sample](http://developer.android.com/ndk/samples/sample_hellojni.html).

Comment: okay... :/ Thanks for your help :)